# Clearing label if page is changed or refreshed

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, email, session-variables

I have created an email form, and when the user click submit. The page would redirect itself to the same page to prevent resubmissions if page is refreshed. Once the page is redirected to itself, a label would display "Thank you." The problem is when I refresh the page or go another page and come back, the label still displays "Thank you," instead of "". Is there a way to clear the Session["Results"] when I refresh the page or change it, or a better solution? Thanks in advance.

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;

public partial class Contact : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["ClickedLink"] = "Contact";

        lblResults.Text = "";

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            lblResults.Text = Session["Results"].ToString();
        }       
    }

    protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Contact.txt");
            string mailBody = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
            mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Name##", txtName.Text);
            mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Email##", txtEmail.Text);
            mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Message##", txtMessage.Text);
            MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
            myMessage.Subject = "Response from web site";
            myMessage.Body = mailBody;
            myMessage.From = new MailAddress("intern2@gmail.com", "Sender Name");
            myMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("intern2@gmail.com", "Receiver Name"));
            myMessage.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text));
            SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            mySmtpClient.Send(myMessage);

            txtName.Text = "";
            txtEmail.Text = "";
            txtMessage.Text = "";
        }

        lblResults.Text = "Thank you";
        Session["Results"] = lblResults.Text;
        Response.Redirect("Contact.aspx");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is add a line to clear the session variable after use:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["ClickedLink"] = "Contact";

    lblResults.Text = "";

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        lblResults.Text = Session["Results"].ToString();

        Session["Results"] = null;
    }       
}
```

In QueryString the user can insert a value manually to show in label.

Answer (score 1):

You can send message in Query String on redirect.

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...

    Response.Redirect("Contact.aspx?msg=Thanks");

}
```

and on PageLoad

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["ClickedLink"] = "Contact";

    lblResults.Text = "";

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["msg"] != null) 
            lblResults.Text = Request.QueryString["msg"];
    }       
}
```

Comment: I ran into an error after I click send. It says 

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

**Exception Details:** System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Yeah the error is in Page_Load and it is on line 20: lblResults.Text = Request.QueryString["msg"].ToString();

Comment: Try remove ".ToString()". and check if is not null:

´   if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       if (Request.QueryString["msg"] != null) 
         lblResults.Text = Request.QueryString["msg"];
    } 
´